# How Can I optimize this query (OR inside AND validation)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I'm having problems with this query:

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3,...,coln FROM MyTable
WHERE col1 = @value1
AND
(
ISNULL(col2,'c') = ISNULL(@value2,ISNULL(col2,'c'))
OR
ISNULL(col3,'c') = ISNULL(@value2,ISNULL(col3,'c'))
)
 AND coln = 'valueN'
```

I have to stop the execution, it's so slow. But editing:

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3,...,coln FROM MyTable
WHERE col1 = @value1
AND
(
ISNULL(col2,'c') = ISNULL(@value2,ISNULL(col2,'c'))
)
AND coln = 'valueN'
```

This query is faster. Can someone help me? How can I replace the or statement or replace the query but validating col1 and col2?.
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you very much guys. Really my query does not use '=' but use 'Like', **sorry about that**. However I use your suggestions to build my query and it works fine:

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3,...,coln FROM MyTable
WHERE col1 like '%' + @value1 + '%'
AND
(
 (@value2 IS NULL)
 OR
  (col2 IS NOT NULL AND col2 LIKE '%' + @value2 + '%')
 OR
 (col3 IS NOT NULL AND col3 LIKE '%' + @value2 + '%')
)
 AND coln = 'valueN'
```

I use this query with a page where I have many fields to filter a search and I need that a col2 textbox apply to col3 in database too, I want to mean, only one textbox for name1 and name2 in database.

Sorry about my wrong question and thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you change the parameterised query depending on whether value2 is null or not? Is there anything obvious in the query plan for the bad case?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Adrian solution works fine, the query  must validate the necesary not like my old queries that validates always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ISNULL(col2,'c') = ISNULL('value2',ISNULL(col2,'c'))
```

is the same as

```
col2 = 'value2' or (col2 is null and 'value2' is null)
```

Replace the occurrences and you will most likely have a better performance.

**Update**

There's one fundamental difference between this solution and the one proposed by @onedaywhen: when the value provided in `'value2'` (which I suppose is just a parameter assembled into a SQL string) is `NULL`, OP only wants to bring back only records where col2 is NULL. Take a closer look into OP's logic, you will see that there. OP's logic **always** filters: when the parameter is `NULL`, OP wants records where `col2 is NULL`.

@onedaywhen's solution brings **every** record when the parameter is `NULL`. Although this is a very common query, **it's not what OP is looking for**.

Comment: Works fine!!. Thanks so much.

Comment: Your assertion ("is the same") is false. Consider that `ISNULL('value2',ISNULL(col2,'c'))` will always evaluate to 'value2'.

Comment: ...even when you correct `'value2'` to `@value2` your suggestion is not equivalent to the OP's!

Comment: @onedaywhen I agree that `value2` should be `@value2`. That said, take a closer look at OP's logic and you will see OP's requirements: the query will always filter! If parameter is NULL, OP wants to bring only records where col2 is NULL, **not** every record.

Comment: Do you agree that if the column and the parameter value are both null then the `ISNULL` logic will consider them to both be `c`? This effectively changes SQL's 3VL logic so that `NULL = NULL` evaluates TRUE for this predicate. See my updated answer for a demonstration :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ISNULL(col2,'c') = ISNULL(@value2,ISNULL(col2,'c'))
```

is the same as

```
( ( col2 = @value2 ) OR ( @value2 IS NULL ) )
```

I'm not sure if this will improve performance, though: I've read that, at least for SQL Server 2005 and earlier, [to get an efficient, scalable and performant solution either use `IF ELSE` control of flow blocks (one per parameter combination) or use dynamic SQL](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/05/17/444.aspx).

---

UPDATE: ...and here's the proof:

---

Query 1: When the parameter is a value that is not null:

```
DECLARE @value2 VARCHAR(10);
SET @value2 = 'Apples';
WITH T 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'When col2 is null', NULL), 
                     (2, 'When col2 is the same value as @value2', 'Apples'), 
                     (3, 'When col2 is not the same value as @value2', 'Oranges')
             ) AS T (ID, narrative, col2)
     )
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(col2,'c') = ISNULL(@value2,ISNULL(col2,'c')) THEN 'T' END AS OP, 
       CASE WHEN ( ( col2 = @value2 ) OR ( @value2 IS NULL ) ) THEN 'T' END AS OneDayWhen, 
       CASE WHEN col2 = @value2 or (col2 is null and @value2 is null) THEN 'T' END AS Adrian
  FROM T;
```

Output 1:

```
ID          narrative                                  col2    OP   OneDayWhen Adrian
----------- ------------------------------------------ ------- ---- ---------- ------
1           When col2 is null                          NULL    NULL NULL       NULL
2           When col2 is the same value as @value2     Apples  T    T          T
3           When col2 is not the same value as @value2 Oranges NULL NULL       NULL
```

Note all agree for all rows :)

---

Query 2: When the parameter is a null:

```
DECLARE @value2 VARCHAR(10);
SET @value2 = NULL;
WITH T 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'When col2 is null', NULL), 
                     (2, 'When col2 is the same value as @value2', 'Apples'), 
                     (3, 'When col2 is not the same value as @value2', 'Oranges')
             ) AS T (ID, narrative, col2)
     )
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN ISNULL(col2,'c') = ISNULL(@value2,ISNULL(col2,'c')) THEN 'T' END AS OP, 
       CASE WHEN ( ( col2 = @value2 ) OR ( @value2 IS NULL ) ) THEN 'T' END AS OneDayWhen, 
       CASE WHEN col2 = @value2 or (col2 is null and @value2 is null) THEN 'T' END AS Adrian
  FROM T;
```

Output 2:

```
ID          narrative                                  col2    OP   OneDayWhen Adrian
----------- ------------------------------------------ ------- ---- ---------- ------
1           When col2 is null                          NULL    T    T          T
2           When col2 is the same value as @value2     Apples  T    T          NULL
3           When col2 is not the same value as @value2 Oranges T    T          NULL
```

Note OP and OneDayWhen match for all rows, Adrian only matches for row ID = 1.

Comment: You are correct. But I would bet that the OP wants Adrian's logic.

Comment: @ypercube: I'd take that wager ;)

Comment: @ypercube Please take your time to read my answer update. Thanks